# /proc/net/tcp Alternative Under Solaris 11

Tags: c, solaris, netstat, opensolaris

On Most Linux Distributions, i was able to list all tcp connections by reading /proc/net/tcp, but this Doesn't exists on solaris, is there a file that i can read tcp connections from on Solaris 11?

thanks.

EDIT: forgot to mention that i'm coding in c.

Comment: (On Linux, you should be using `ss -t` to list them. The procfs interface is only there because of the compat screamers, but it has been stuck in the past for more than 10 years now.)

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to rewrite `netstat`, I suggest looking at the source code for it: https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/cmd/cmd-inet/usr.bin/netstat/netstat.c

The important parts are `mibopen`, which opens `/dev/arp` and pushes the `tcp` STREAMS module onto it, and `mibget` which actually requests the connection information. The code is a bit complicated, so I suggest stepping through the code in a debugger to understand how it works. The key syscalls are `open`, `ioctl`, `putmsg`, and `getmsg`.

If you just want to see what sockets a process has open, you can inspect `/proc/PID/fd`, as in `pfiles`: https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/cmd/ptools/pfiles/pfiles.c

Comment: i looked at it already, i just couldn't figure out whats going on there or how it works, its not like the linux one at all.

Comment: You didn't say exactly what you're trying to do, but I updated my answer to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use `netstat -an` or [`pcp`](http://www.unix.ms/pcp/)

Comment: im writing my own code, sorry if i didnt specify that in the question